# 'Evolves into' versus 'evolves to'

Tags: grammar

Which is proper/best?  Are neither proper?

> As the market **evolves into** commodity based pricing the low cost
>   providers will dominate.

> As the market **evolves to** commodity based pricing the low cost providers
>   will dominate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option I supposed, as in [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/evolve)'s exact example:

> [no object]   ‘the company has evolved *into* a major chemical manufacturer’.
>
> [with object] ‘each school must evolve its own way of working’.

Answer (score 1):

Since the process of evolving gives the market new qualities, but does not change it into a completely different thing, I would use 'evolves to'. Using 'evolves into', as in this sentence,

> Their rallies evolved into elaborate collective rituals for loyalists.
>
> Washington Post Oct 21, 2016

implies that it is changing into a different thing, i.e. not a market or a different market. Although it is the best of the two choices,'Evolves to' is not very common, and it is probably better to say 'evolves towards'.

> As the market evolves towards commodity based pricing, the low cost providers will dominate.

Comment: Good answer.  The market and software/service both evolve.   But I agree the media market is a whole different set of services than it was 40 years ago but it is still essentially the same market.